# Algorithm and script definition

Tags: algorithm

I hear the term algorithm use often and have been confused by the context I am seeing it in on this site sometimes so I thought I would try and clear up my understanding.

To me an algorithm is some for of mathematical process such as this

```
uint UPDC16( unsigned char a, uint crc )
{
    uint b,p;
    a^=crc; crc=(crc>>8)|(a<<8); p=a^(a>>4); p^=(p>>2); b=a; a>>=1;
    if( (p^(p>>1))&1 ) { crc^=0x0001; a|=0x80; }
    if( b & 1 ) crc^=0x0040; b=a; a^=(crc>>8);
    if( a & 1 ) crc^=0x0080; a>>=1;
    if( b & 0x80 ) a|=0x80;
    crc = (crc&0x00ff)|(a<<8);
    return crc;
}
```

Where as I thought that as this performed an action (rotating image) through nester if statments and not a mathmatical function it was not an algorithm but a function.

```
for (int block_x = 0; block_x < 2048; block_x+=8)
 {
    for (int block_y = 0; blocky_y < 2048; block_y+=8)
    { 
       // this is the inner-loop that processes a block
       // of 8x8 pixels.
       for (int x= 0; x<8; x++)
         for (int y=0; y<8; y++)
            dest[x+block_x][y+block_y] = src[y+block_y][x+block_x]
    }
 }
```

I have googled it but I am looking for an experienced coders explanation. can anyone help explain algorithms to me ?

The other thing that is bothering me is that I have seen the term "script it" several times and do not understand. I have heard there are scripting languages like lua (may be wrong).

Do they mean to used these languages or is a "script" a special method of coding ?

I mostly use c/c++ if this makes any difference.

Comment: The examples you provide are *implementations* of algorithms. An algorithm is best described in words, maybe as pseudo-code. A script is a program written in a scripting language. Neither C nor C++ could be described as 'scripting languages'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question : for me an algorithm can be an idea such as "to compute the sum of all the elements of the array you need to.....", a function (there is an input and un output and some steps in between) or a serie of mathematical operation.

So an algorithm would be a serie of steps that allow to go from somewhere to somewhere else (going from your home to your work using the subway is also an algorithm).

For your second question : there are two big types (I'm simplifying) of programming languages, the "compiled" ones and the "interprated" ones and among the latters you have the interactive ones or scripting languages. Also, generally speaking, scripting languages are considered high-levels ones : you can do powerful things in a few lines that together are forming a script.

Of course some scripting language can also be compiled....